# How is it possible to transfer image from activity to another activity?

Tags: android

I did not manage to get a picture from activity to another activity.

this is my part of the code:

this is one activity:

```
button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   EditText website = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText));
    String g = website.getText().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent(CoohseImage.this, MainActivity.class);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bs);
    intent.putExtra("image", bs.toByteArray());
    intent.putExtra("message", g);
    startActivity(intent);
}});
```

And this is the second activity:

```
targetImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.targetimage);
Intent intent = getIntent();
message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
// b = intent.getByteExtra("image", "dfdd");
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText(message);
if(getIntent().hasExtra("image")) {
     ImageView targetImage = new ImageView(this);
     Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image"), 0, getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image").length);
     targetImage.setImageBitmap(b);
}
```

Comment: Why do you wrote this line : __ImageView targetImage = new ImageView(this);__ after this one __targetImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.targetimage);__?

Comment: I deleted the irrelevant lines Pantry still not working

Comment: Are you sure that you need this line : __ImageView targetImage = new ImageView(this);__ you've overrided your ImageView, and set image to it, so you will not see the image at your ImageView

Comment: yes, i deleted it and it's not working                                                              I press the button and it just does not respond

Answer (score 2):

A better approach would be to just share the source of your bitmap between the Activities and load the bitmap in `onCreate()` of the newly created Activity.

Answer (score 0):

This is not recommended because it costs a lot of memory.

in first `Activity`

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, second.class);
                    i.putExtra("data", bitmap)
                    startActivity(i);
```

in Second Activity

```
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    Bitmap bmp = b.getParcelable("data");
```

#### I recommed to you saving the image to disk and open it in the second activity!

Comment: I tried to change it but it crashes and a problem occurs in a series of: Bitmap bmp = b.getParcelable ("data");

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass the reference to the object

```
int image = R.drawable.imageinquestion;

Intent i = new Intent(Act1.this, Act2.class);
i.putExtra("IMAGE", image);
startActivity(i);
```

In Act2

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if(b!=null)
{
image = b.get("IMAGE");//or getInt() or getString()
}
```

If its a website, send the link as a String

Comment: My bad, I have made the changes.

Answer (score 0):

1-First you need to save bitmap in a file.

2-To get bitmap from image view:

```
imageview.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm=imageview.getDrawingCache();
```

3-To save it in a file:

```
 OutputStream fOut = null;
Uri outputFileUri;
 try {
File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
  + File.separator + "folder_name" + File.separator);
root.mkdirs();


 File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, "myPicName.jpg");
outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
fOut = new FileOutputStream(sdImageMainDirectory);


  } catch (Exception e) {
Toast.makeText(this, "Error occured. Please try again later.",
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}
 try {
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
fOut.flush();
fOut.close();


  } catch (Exception e) {
}
```

4- Instead of sharing sending bitmap, send outputFileUri with intent to next activity.

5-Retrieve Image from outputFileUri to image view in second activity:

```
 Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(outputFileUri );
 imageView.setImageURI(uri);
```

Comment: only this code in the second activity? :                                                       Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(outputFileUri );                             imageView.setImageURI(uri);                                                                          the second class  is not know "outputFileUri "

Comment: Mate..outputFileUri  is just a reference  in which you will receive fileUri from intent.You can rename it whatever you want. outputFileUri in second activity has no relation with outputFileUri in first activity.
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(uri);//this uri is what you will get from intent

Answer (score -1):

You have a limit of data you can send via Intent using bundle, so i strongly recommend you do as Elenasys: Save in disk and open in the target activity.(You can use the intent to send the path).